# Group elements in HEAD tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Im working on a `AJAX` page system. When you press a link the `ajax` get called and retrieves data from the page that you requested.

My problem is, in that page file there are some data that needs to be placed in the `head` tag. I've tried the jQuery function `.appendTo()`, but when you visit another page it just keeps appending.

So what I am looking for is a way to create a element group in the head tag so that the content is being replaced on the specific page like `$("#head").html(headData)`;

How do I solve this? Since you cant put a `div` in the `head` tag, I have no idea how to group the elements.

One way is to add a class with the page name to every element. But Im looking for a more efficient method. I want every developer working with this system to just write the code without having in mind to do some specific task for getting it to the `head`.

Anyone got an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using class. You can even check for element with class in HEAD length, and do nothing if already there. Maybe you'd have better to explain why would you need to add some `datas` in HEAD?

Comment: With that in mind I found a solution. Writing the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it like this:

First the function checks the head for all elements with the class "`ajaxHeadObject`" and removes them.

The function then adds the data to a element with the id "`head`". Then foreach element in that object it adds the class "`ajaxHeadObject`" and appends all of the objects to the head.

```
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "head.php",
            success: function (data){

                $("head .ajaxHeadObject").each( function () {

                    $(this).remove();

                });

                $("#head").html(data);
                $("#head").children().each( function () {

                    $(this).addClass("ajaxHeadObject");
                    $(this).appendTo("head");

                }, function () {

                    $("#head").remove();

                })

            }

        })
```

Let me know what you think of this.